# Removing Background and Detect shape With C program

Tags: c, image, image-processing

I want to remove background and detect the shape of the egg [image: Sample Picture] from the picture and calculate the oval shape. What would be the best approach for this, I want do it with C.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the every pixel value, it will be a 32 bit RGB format. Each color will have unique value. Filter only yellow color values as well their positions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 4):

You can extract exact oval shape by trying following algorithm:

1. Extract Red Channel from image. It will look as follows:
   [image: RedChannel]
2. Apply threshold and suppress all pixel values below 150. It will give you exact oval shape as below:
   [image: OvalShape]

I have written code for this in C++. Following is the function I used for shape extraction:

```
int main() {
    cv::Mat input = imread("image.jpg");
    cv::Mat im_splt[3];
    split(input, im_splt);
    cv::Mat RedChannel = im_splt[2];
    cv::Mat OvalShape = RedChannel > 150;
}
```